# I just want half that/I want the half of that

Tags: word-usage

Someone offers me a tortilla. I want just half of that tortilla. So what should I use:

> I just want half. Could you please cut it.
>
> I just want the half of that.
>
> I just want half that.

What should be used :#1,#2 or #3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in other languages, there are many ways to say this in English.  All three of your sentences may be appropriate, depending on the context.

Your first sentence is literal, and explains exactly what you want. Assuming that the listener will know how to cut something in half, a shorter version might be:

> I just want half of that.

Your second sentence uses the definite article "the" and would be appropriate if you refer to a defined portion:

> I just want **the half without any brown spots**.
>
> I just want **the half closer to me**.

The third sentence is an abbreviated expression that is generally used more when talking about *quantities or amounts*, rather than individual items.  For example, suppose I pour myself a glass of wine and then offer you some.  You might respond:

> I just want half that

as short for  "half the *amount*" that I poured myself.  Or suppose I make you a bowl of soup, but you're not very hungry.  You could say "I just want half that" to indicate you can't eat a full bowl, so you would like only half of a bowl.

You can use this with something like a tortilla (a singular object that needs to be divided in half) but there it may be more common to say, "I just want half *of* that".

That being said: In casual conversation native speakers often drop certain articles and prepositions, so you may hear many variations on these expressions.

Comment: And what about: I want half that much. Has “of” been skipped here. Is it : I want half of that much. Or does this mean something else?

Comment: So is the sentence in the comment right too?

Comment: And in quantity,like soup, can it be:I want half of that.( I added "of" in your sentence,does it sound natural?

Comment: Andrew:That being said: In casual conversation native speakers often drop certain articles and prepositions, so you may hear many variations on these expressions.                                        It's about English: So,in casual conversation,in case of tortilla,will "of" be dropped?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  I'm not sure I understand your questions.  Again, there are many ways to say this in English, some more formal than others.  It would be a lot of work to list each one, and all the variations.

Comment: Andrew you'd had.said that in case of singular,solid food items,the use of "of" is more common. And then you'd said that "articles" are dropped in casual conversations. So will "of" be dropped too while referring to a tortilla too?